# Can the standard output of NSTask be used to generate an xml file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am writing an objective-c/cocoa application that has to utilize a java utility app. So I plan on using NSTask to call the java app. I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to communicate between the cocoa and java app. Is it possible to send an xml formatted string through standard out of the java app, and get the cocoa app to use that to create an xml object to then be deserialized and used for its data?

Comment: Do you have control over the source code of the Java utility application? Is the utility supposed to run continuously whilst the Cocoa application is running?

Comment: Yes, the java utility will be written by me. The java utility just does a particular task, so it is kicked off when needed during the run time of the cocoa app.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [standardOutput](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTask/standardOutput) method. That will give you an [NSPipe](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPipe_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPipe) object that you can then grab a [NSFileHandle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFileHandle) from via the [fileHandleForReading](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPipe_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPipe/fileHandleForWriting). You'll just want to [readDataToEndOfFile](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/readDataToEndOfFile) on the handle to get back an [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSData) object which you can pass off to [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you want tree based XML handling. Otherwise, you'll want to look at [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for event based parsing. Both of the XML references have corresponding guides that will be useful.

All of this is pretty much right out of the docs from your starting point of NSTask.

Comment: the `setStandard*` methods on `NSTask` will also accept `NSFileHandle` objects, in addition to `NSPipe` objects.  This is better if the amount of data you're reading/writing may exceeding the amount allowed by the pipe.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I think this will do the trick. I'll give it a try.